# How can I get the last accessed time of a folder?

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to make a code gets a folder last accessed time.

I'm trying to use os.getatime() method. So I can get the last accessed time.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-getatime-method/

But when I try to get the last access time it always gives me my current time.


Here is the code (Well its same as the one about the link above.)

```
import os
import time

path = r"D:\MinecraftOrgin"

  
# Get the time of last
# access of the specified
# path since the epoch
access_time = os.path.getatime(path)
print("Last access time since the epoch:", access_time)
  
# convert the time in
# seconds since epoch
# to local time
local_time = time.ctime(access_time)
print("Last access time(Local time):", local_time)
```

Also "D:\MinecraftOrgin" is belong to a file that i dont even remember. I am sure that i did not open it for a long time and did not open it to look at the path i just wrote the path by hand.

So I am sure it's last access time shouldnt be today/right now.(The hours is same either.)

And I also tried different folders like that.

I don't realy get why this happens. Is there a better way to do this??

Comment: By default Windows doesn't maintain access times, see https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/129/enable-last-access-time.html

Comment: The problem isn't the way you're asking, the problem is that it's not being updated in the first place. Read that document to find out how to enable updating.